# Qual API usar para criar uma galeria

Tags: android

Preciso criar uma galeria mas não sei como carregar as imagens do cartão nas view.
Alguém pode me ajudar a qual API usar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai usar uma biblioteca chamada [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) ou [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Elas tratam de carregar as imagens nas listas sem travar o Android.

Exemplo do uso:

```
Glide.with(this).load(imagem).into(imageView);
//this é o contexto
//imagem pode ser um link da internet, um drawable...qualquer coisa carrega.
//imageView é o lugar onde vai carregar
```

Funciona tanto na activity quanto em fragmentos ou em adaptadores.

Comment: obrigado ajudou muito